# Uncaught SyntaxError: 59 Laravel 8 + Vue 2?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have Laravel 8 + Vue 2 application everything locally working just fine, when I upload it to production it is working on the web version but on mobile the content show and disappear immediately!

I check console i got this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: 59
    bs https://XXXX.com/js/app.js?id=a6914376b5a69162c038:1
```

i open the app file the error in this code! :

```
function bs(e, t, n, r) {
    const o = new SyntaxError(String(e));
    return o.code = e,
    o.loc = t,
    o
}
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: It looks like your js file could not be loaded?

Comment: @Aless55 it works in the desktop version but when I use (responsive design mode) in the browser and refresh I got the error and the app does not work!

Comment: do you use some user agent detection or something similar?

Comment: Post your `app.js` from `resources` folder (not minified version from `public`)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto   https://ibb.co/M8Dd2bR  -- https://ibb.co/410HR8x -- https://ibb.co/mXh7Kvj

Comment: @Aless55 I'm using Cloudflare

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto it is a lot of code stack won't accept it

Comment: Is 52 lines of code (based on your pics) too much for you? You can still post it on SO.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto it is not about me, I tried to post it but the Stackoverflow validate me that your post contains a lot of codes